# Can SML functors take non-structure arguments (Ullman 8.3.4)?

Tags: sml, functor

I just want to check my understanding here, I'm working through the functor chapter of *Elements of ML Programming* as a refresh and one of the problems requires writing a functor that "takes only an integer *b* as input." I can write a functor which is applied as follows:

```
structure HashFn100 = MakeHashFn(struct val i = 100 end);
```

but not

```
structure HashFn100 = MakeHashFn(100);
```

as the problem statement seems to imply. Is the wording confusing me and my current functor is correct or is there a way to apply a functor to a non-struct that I'm missing? Unfortunately this exercise does not have an answer in the solutions manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
structure HashFn100 = MakeHashFn(val i = 100)
```

which is syntactic sugar for the first form you showed. The second isn't legal -- syntactically, a functor argument must either be a module (structure or identifier) or a sequence of declarations (as a shorthand for a structure).

Comment: Is this syntactic sugar unofficial? In the SML spec where it defines the syntax for "functor application", it doesn't seem to mention this.

Comment: @xyz, it is defined as a "derived form" in Appendix A, see the second box in Figure 18.